# Method Over riding and Inheritance and Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, runtimeexception, overriding

Can a method in a subclass override a method in the parent class and throw a run time exception when the method in the parent class throws no exception? Something like this:

```
class X { public void foo() { System.out.print("X "); } }

public class SubB extends X {
    public void foo() throws RuntimeException {
        super.foo();
        if (true) 
            throw new RuntimeException();
        System.out.print("B ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubB().foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because runtime exceptions aren't part of the method signature. (You can add them but the compiler doesn't care, they're just documentation.)

I think the rationale is that RuntimeExceptions are usually programmer errors, like NPEs or going out of bounds of an array, so it doesn't make sense to try to restrict them the way that checked exceptions are restricted. You can't make a rule saying, this method (and any method overriding it) can never ever throw a NullPointerException, because the JVM doesn't make those kinds of guarantees.

In the Java Language Specification under [Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2) it says:

> The unchecked exception classes (§11.1.1) are exempted from
>   compile-time checking.
>
> Of the unchecked exception classes, error classes are exempted because
>   they can occur at many points in the program and recovery from them is
>   difficult or impossible. A program declaring such exceptions would be
>   cluttered, pointlessly. Sophisticated programs may yet wish to catch
>   and attempt to recover from some of these conditions.
>
> Of the unchecked exception classes, runtime exception classes are
>   exempted because, in the judgment of the designers of the Java
>   programming language, having to declare such exceptions would not aid
>   significantly in establishing the correctness of programs. Many of the
>   operations and constructs of the Java programming language can result
>   in exceptions at run-time. The information available to a Java
>   compiler, and the level of analysis a compiler performs, are usually
>   not sufficient to establish that such run-time exceptions cannot
>   occur, even though this may be obvious to the programmer. Requiring
>   such exception classes to be declared would simply be an irritation to
>   programmers.
>
> For example, certain code might implement a circular data structure
>   that, by construction, can never involve null references; the
>   programmer can then be certain that a NullPointerException cannot
>   occur, but it would be difficult for a Java compiler to prove it. The
>   theorem-proving technology that is needed to establish such global
>   properties of data structures is beyond the scope of this
>   specification.

Comment: But what about _over riding methods are not supposed to throw more restrictive exceptions_?

Comment: That only matters for checked exceptions.

Comment: And because runtime exceptions are not checked its ok, right? Thanks!